# kubernetes: bind to a specific node network interface

Tags: kubernetes

In the case of (non-managed) k8s nodes having 2 interfaces, one for mgmt one for app traffic, is it possible to restrict all k8s traffic including k8s services to listen to one interface? I.e. k8s services to not listen to the management interface.

To clarify, each of the nodes including the control node, have 2 intefaces, I want all k8s services to LISTEN on one interface only (or ACCEPT from only one). This is for both my kubernetes services and kube-system's ns services (kube-proxy, kube-api, etc), weave as well. Currently k8s binds and listens on all interfaces (and subnets) for everything.

K8S network policies seems to only restrict traffic based on source or target remote IP, they cannot restrict based on dest IP of incoming packets.

Using iptables does not be possible for services unless hostnetwork=true, which may cause issues with service discovery and routing, and this would not cover weave an the rest.

No ChatGPT crap please.